# jsfiddle example of jQuery isn't applying on jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I created jquery dropdown menu in slider. and wants to change its view state like ""https://jsfiddle.net/user23435/tzrunfjd/1/"" and i added slide effect on dropdown menu like this https://ibb.co/QdRWqRy . If I click on one slide it opens but by clicking other slide the previousone close and then by clicking it again it opens,,,,,,,,How can i apply this https://jsfiddle.net/user23435/tzrunfjd/1/ into my code which is given below

html code:

```
 <div class="carousel slide col-md-10 col-xs-12" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" 
    id="myCarousel">
 </div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
   $('.create-meeting-btn').click(function(){
     $('.create-meeting-form').stop().slideToggle();   //stop or delay(1000)
   });

  $('.upcoming-btn').click(function(){
      $('.upcoming-table').stop().slideToggle(); 
  });

  $('.completed-btn').click(function(){
      $('.completed-table').stop().slideToggle();
  }); 

  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
     pause: true,
     interval: false,
  });


 function setMeetingCarausel() {
   let meetingsCopy = utils.setSliders(Array.from(meetings));

   let html = '<div class="carousel-inner no-padding">';

 meetingsCopy.map((meeting, index) => {
      html += `<div class="item ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}">`;
      meeting.map(m => {
      let className = m.status === 'completed' ? 'btn btn-warning btn-lg dashboard-icon' : 'btn btn-success   
     btn-lg dashboard-icon'
 html += `
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" onclick="handleClickMeetingItem('${m._id}')">
       <span href="" class="${className}" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
       <p style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">${m.subject}</p>
       <p style="padding-top: 12px; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">${utils.convertDate(m.date)}</p>
       <p style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold;">( ${m.status} )</p>
      </span>
  </div>
  `;
  });
   html += `</div>`;
  })
 html += `
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="margin-left:63px; color:grey;"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="margin-right:140px; color:grey;"></span>
  </a>
 `;

  $('#myCarousel').html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jsfiddle link html code in your jquery html variable as you want but be careful about its class names because these classes handle the functionality and use this mainmenu function in script tag as it.

```
   function mainmenu(){
    jQuery(".topm").click(function(){
    jQuery('.content').slideUp("fast");
    jQuery(this).find('.content').slideDown("fast");
   });
   }
```

but call this mainmenu function in the end of your setMeetingCarausel function. This mainmenu function call inside the setMeetingCarausel not outside.
jQuery(document).mouseup function use as it, in the end of script tags.

Comment: its class names are change and i used your code same as it is in my code but nthing changes, its same as before

Comment: Show me your new code then i can give you the suggestion.

Comment: complete code is here it has two sliders (sliders are same),,,,,,,,,paste.ofcode.org/zNUPzb3AuNQZUUqAAzZmjL

Comment: in browser URL tab just paste "paste.ofcode.org/zNUPzb3AuNQZUUqAAzZmjL"

Comment: You change your code this way "paste.ofcode.org/faAUpnVj3eHQ8kCNbq4teR" and use html classes of your jsfiddle reference link where you want to trigger droop down.

Comment: plz check these pics https://ibb.co/Y7cNTNV      https://ibb.co/w6ZFtXY      https://ibb.co/QdRWqRy     u will get know everything

Comment: by clicking on any slide (or btn also, which is showing as main btn in screenshots)

Comment: please follow instruction in it. "paste.ofcode.org/YcH7jFcAsfVVZQZujE9Xic"

Comment: css code use in head > style tag and replace jquery code your existing code

Comment: the data is manual init and it is also effecting the style of page as i show u my code i just wants to implement this in that code

Comment: send me the link of personal chat

Comment: This is the best example to use drop down.clean the css as your requirement and use it. Visit https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar